# Detect list of beacon with Altbeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am trying to get the list of the nearby beacons with the Android Beacon Library. I was following this [sample](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) but as a newbie I found it too complicated. I don't want to detect beacons in the backgroun, I don't want to detect regions entry ... I just want to have the list of the actual visible beacons. 
In the onCreate method of my MainActivity class I just added this code and hoped that this will start the ranging or Monitoring but this didn't happen. Did someone have and idea what is the problem or how to use this two classes ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        MonitoringActivity monitoringActivity = new MonitoringActivity();
        RangingActivity rangingActivity = new RangingActivity();

    }

    @Override
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do get a list of visible beacons, you want to do beacon "ranging".  You don't need to use the two separate Activity classes mentioned in the examples.  You can just copy the relevant parts of the Ranging example into your own Activity.

So do this:

1. Remove the references to `MonitoringActivity` and `RangingActivity` from your class.
2. Add the following to your class:

Change your class definition to be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {
```

Add the following code to your `onCreate` method:

```
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
    // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
```

Add the following methods to your class:

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override 
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", "I see a beacon that is about "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");        
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

The list of visible beacons is what is accessed inside the `for (Beacon beacon : beacons)` line.

Comment: Code is deprecated